# Can i load second viewDidload in first viewDidload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsnotificationcenter

Hi guys i have a dual viewcontroller.

My firstviewcontroller have a button and this button send NSNotification  and secontviewController receive this notification and NSLOG any string.

But if i dont load secontView;  my Notification is dont work ..
This codes in my firstViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)tapper:(id)sender {


   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Twitter" object:nil];
}
```

and this codes in my secontViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector( receiveNotificaiton: ) name:@"Twitter" object:nil];

}


-(void)receiveNotificaiton: (NSNotification *) notification {
NSLog(@"TWİTTER");
}
```

How can i load   second viewDidload in first viewDidload or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your first view controller to present the second one. Correct?

If so you should not be using notifications. You can simply present the second view controller from the first, take a look at ["Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the right way post a notification to a view controller which doesn't exist yet because (as you said) it can't execute the istruction for becoming observer. So a solution can be present the second view controller and passing the notification information. Using the notification center is a good solution if the second view controller is the top view controleller and something else post the notification. I hope i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with prepareForSegue method , thx them all.